# CAS with OpenID Connect - How to set Redirect URI parameters using "?" instead of "#" after callback

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, openid-connect

I have CAS with OIDC installed and I have added a service as follows and it's working fine :

```
 {
        "implicit": true,
        "logoutType": "BACK_CHANNEL",
        "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.OidcRegisteredService",
        "evaluationOrder": 1,
        "clientId": "TEST",
        "bypassApprovalPrompt": true,
        "jsonFormat": true,
        "jwks": "file:\/etc\/cas\/jwks\/\/enc-test-42.pub.jwks",
        "signIdToken": true,
        "description": "Test",
        "generateRefreshToken": true,
        "idTokenEncryptionEncoding": "A128GCM",
        "name": "Test client",
        "clientSecret": "TEST",
        "id": 42,
        "idTokenEncryptionAlg": "RSA-OAEP-256",
        "scopes": ["java.util.HashSet", ["openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone"]],
        "serviceId": "https:\/\/redirect-host/callback",
        "encryptIdToken": true
    }
```

In order to login using CAS, I'm calling this URL :

```
http://cas-server/oidc/authorize?response_type=id_token+token&client_id=TEST&redirect_uri=https:\/\/redirect-host/callback&scope=openid+profile+email+phone+address
```

Login works fine but after being redirected from CAS to callback url, the accessToken is being appended to callback url with "#" not "?".

```
https://redirect-host/callback#accessToken=.....
```

Can I change "#" to "?" ?
I need to have parameters with ? so that I can read them in the callback server. (using $_GET in PHP for example)

In CAS source code, I found that Redirect URL is being built in "[OAuth20TokenAuthorizationResponseBuilder.java](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/master/support/cas-server-support-oauth/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/support/oauth/web/response/callback/OAuth20TokenAuthorizationResponseBuilder.java)".

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on OIDC but **#** is a fragment identifier in the URI. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) it should

> Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they retrieve a document, and without help from a local application (see below) fragments do not participate in HTTP redirections.

You can find more information in OIDC specification. There is a java-script example in [chapter 15.5.3 of OIDC specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#FragmentNotes) how to extract information after fragment identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to study the OIDC protocol to understand what `response_type=id_token+token`  means, why you're calling it, and then you need to study what `implicit:true` does and why you have indeed set it to true.

In short, the mechanics you have chosen simply require the use of `#`. Switch to a different response/grant type and then you can take advantage of query strings, etc.